# How to show the $f. (g .h)$ is a reparametrization of $(f .g). h ?$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Now days Im reading Allen Hatcher book

I have some confusion in Allen Hatcher book

My confusion is given below in red line

[image]

Author didn't explain in detail

**My doubt** :How to show the $f. (g .h)$ is a reparametrization
of $(f .g). h ?$

Comment: How do you interpret the last part of the sentence, after the part you underlined?

Comment: actually that part was my confusion @BrianMoehring so i post my doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to write the explicit definitions of the two compositions of paths and $\varphi$:

$(f\cdot (g\cdot h))(t)$ is:

$f(2t)$ if $t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$

$g(4t-2)$ if $t\in[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$

$h(4t-3)$ if $t\in[\frac{3}{4},1]$.

$((f\cdot g)\cdot h)(t)$ is:

$f(4t)$ if $t\in[0,\frac{1}{4}]$

$g(4t-1)$ if $t\in[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]$

$h(2t-1)$ if $t\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$.

$\varphi(t)$ is:

$\frac{t}{2}$ if $t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$

$t-\frac{1}{4}$ if $t\in[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$

$2t-1$ if $t\in[\frac{3}{4},1]$.

Now, using the explicit definitions, you just have to check case by case (3 cases: $t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$,$t\in[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$ and $t\in[\frac{3}{4},1]$ ) that $((f\cdot g)\cdot h)(\varphi(t))=(f\cdot (g\cdot h))(t)$.